# How to retrieve all reports from Xero?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, xero-api

I try to get a list of all reports and put them to google sheet by google-script. I have function:

```
function getListOfAllReports()
{
    var oauth = new OAuth(),

    response = oauth.request('/api.xro/2.0/reports/');             // empty array
    response = oauth.request('/api.xro/2.0/reports/BalanceSheet'); // true
    response = oauth.request('/api.xro/2.0/reports/BankSummary');  // true
    response = oauth.request('/api.xro/2.0/reports/TrialBalance'); // true

    if(response.success)
        return {success: true,  message: response.message};
    else
        return {success: false, message: response.message};
}
```

I thought, when my request is `'/reports'` without report name, I'll get a list, but my response is an empty array.

```
{
    "Id": SomeId,
    "Status": "OK",
    "ProviderName": MyProviderName,
    "DateTimeUTC": "\/Date(timestamp)\/",
    "Reports": []
}
```

I didn't find answer for this question in Xero API.

**Question:** Can I get a list? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no function to retrieve a list of all available Xero API's Reports.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/reports

Comment: Sorry, that here, but: did I understand correctly, that I can retrieve only 12 reports, which are presented in documentation (that I can't get custom reports) ?